# Replace values in a pandas df based off values in another column

Tags: python, pandas, replace

I am trying to replace values in multiple `columns` if the value in another column is equal to a specific value. For the `df` below I want to replace all `integers` will an empty value if `Col A is == ABC`

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({          
    'B' : [10,20,30,40,50],
    'A' : ['ABC','DEF','XYZ','ABC','DEF'],          
    'C' : [1,1,1,1,1],              
    })
```

Output:

```
    B    A  C
0  10  ABC  1
1  20  DEF  1
2  30  XYZ  1
3  40  ABC  1
4  50  DEF  1
```

So I want to replace the integers in Col B,C when A is equal to ABC. I have tried this

```
mask = df.A != 'ABC'
col = ['B','C']
df = df.loc[mask, col].replace('')
```

But it only selects the values I want to replace. I'm hoping to produce:

```
    B    A  C
0  10  ABC  1
1      DEF   
2      XYZ   
3  40  ABC  1
4      DEF
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`select_dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.select_dtypes.html) with `np.integer` or `np.number` if want select all numeric columns and then set empty string by condition with `loc`:

```
mask = df.A != 'ABC'
#if want select all integer columns
col = df.select_dtypes(np.integer).columns
#if want select columns by names
#col = ['B','C']
df.loc[mask, col] = ''
print (df)
    B    A  C
0  10  ABC  1
1      DEF   
2      XYZ   
3  40  ABC  1
4      DEF
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use

```
In [189]: df[['B', 'C']] = df[['B', 'C']].where(df.A.eq('ABC'), '')

In [190]: df
Out[190]:
    B    A  C
0  10  ABC  1
1      DEF
2      XYZ
3  40  ABC  1
4      DEF
```

Answer (score 0):

Pandas `apply`:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({          
    'B' : [10,20,30,40,50],
    'A' : ['ABC','DEF','XYZ','ABC','DEF'],          
    'C' : [1,1,1,1,1],              
    })
print(df.apply(lambda row: [i if isinstance(i,str) else '' for i in row.tolist()] if row['A']!='ABC' else row,axis=1))
```

Output:

```
     A   B  C
0  ABC  10  1
1  DEF       
2  XYZ       
3  ABC  40  1
4  DEF
```